# How do I make xcodebuild select right target when their products have the same name?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process, ios-frameworks

I got a project to make an iOS app, lets call it Foo. It dependen/uses another project, lets call it Bar that makes a framework, Bar.framework. In the Build Phase of my iOS app Foo, I have added Bar.framework under 'Embedded frameworks'.

This works fine. Except when I try to build on the command line it fails. I build with:

```
xcodebuild DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES DSTROOT=/tmp/Foo.dst -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo build
```

The reason it fails is that I have two targets Bar-OSX and Bar-iOS which both create a framework named Bar.framework. xcodebuild ends up choosing Bar-OSX when building. I can delete the tareget, then the compile will work as Bari-iOS gets chosen.

I could probably fix this by keeping the product names different but I don't want the code using the framework to import a framework with different name just because it is from either iOS or OSX. Is there a way of solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking the wrong framework appears to have been caused by a bug in xcodebuild. By using [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) which is a drop in replacement the correct framework was selected and built.